# Need clarification about what happens to the file changes after git soft reset

Tags: git, github, terminal, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I committed and pushed the code(my bad) and did a soft reset after that. I want to add and re-commit the same changes again but when I execute git status, I don't see the file changes which I'm looking to re-commit. Does that mean those file changes are gone after soft reset? Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

It had package.json files too. How do I pick up the changes I'd made to the files before soft reset?

Comment: What commands are you running to perform a soft reset? Can you include the commands you are trying?

Comment: @Prabu git reset --soft HEAD~1 and git push branchname --force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does that mean those file changes are gone after soft reset?

No: a soft reset only moves HEAD. It does not touch the files or the index.
You can check the content of those files on disk yourself: you should still see the modification.

A `git reset` (now that HEAD is on the previous commit) should be enough to reset the index, unstaging those files.